# Javascript/JQuery-event to recognize all request-starts/ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxComplete`, I wonder if there is an event, to trigger all *request starts* and *request complete* events?
Because when I execute a form.submit, ajaxStart and ajaxComplete is apparently not triggered.

I would like to display a generic load animation for all requests.

My current implementation (for ajax-requests):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (event, request, settings) {
     $("#ajax-loader").show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    if ($.active == 1) {
        $("#ajax-loader").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't reliably update the DOM after a standard form submission (ie. non-AJAX) request is made, as the page will immediately be unloaded and the contents of the DOM will be removed from memory.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Thank you for clarifiction.

Comment: One trick is to use a setTimeout wrapper on your form submit. You see this a lot with analytics, where you might need to fire some tracking event before the page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `window.onsubmit` to check when a form is sent. 
But you should always send everythings via AJAX if you wish to use this technology.